# On redirection external JS is not working in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I am creating an app using react.js and  Node.js and Using react-router-dom 4 for Front end routing.

I am using jquery for AJAX request. There is user login api,when User logged in with  credentials then redirecting to Dashboard page by using `this.props.history.push('/dashboard')`

```
UserLoginAPI(){
        let formData = this.state.form;
        $.ajax({ 
            url:BASEURL+CONSTANT.login,
            type:'POST',
            data:formData,
            success:(data)=>{  
                let form = this.state.form;
                this.setState({popUpMessage:data.data });
                this.setState({showPopUp:true});
                this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
            },
            error:(err)=>{ 
                this.setState({popUpMessage:err.responseJSON.message || 'Some Undefined Error Occured.'});
                this.setState({showPopUp:true}) ;
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

After successful login user is redirecting to dashboard page but its external plain javascript is not working well. May be there is some issue in rendering in Page. I am stuck in this.
Below is the route configuration

```
<Router>
        <div className="App"> 
          <Header />
          <Slider />
          <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route  path='/register' component={Register} />
                <Route  path='/login' component={Login} />
                <Route  path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
          </Switch>

        </div>
      </Router>
```

I am not able to find out whats going wrong. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

How do you import your UserLoginAPI ? maybe your example code is not enough. If function is in class scope you have to use arrow functions to bind the class context, if API's method resides outside you have to return a Promise() from your method and resolve the result in your component.

```js
// In-class method
UserLoginAPI= () => {
        let formData = this.state.form;
        $.ajax({ 
            url:BASEURL+CONSTANT.login,
            type:'POST',
            data:formData,
            success:(data)=>{  
                let form = this.state.form;
                this.setState({popUpMessage:data.data });
                this.setState({showPopUp:true});
                this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
            },
            error:(err)=>{ 
                this.setState({popUpMessage:err.responseJSON.message || 'Some Undefined Error Occured.'});
                this.setState({showPopUp:true}) ;
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

```js
// Return promise

MyFunction(myParams) {
       return $.ajax({
            url: myParams.url,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(expenseSet.toJSON())
        });
}
```

Comment: `UserLoginAPI()`  function is in class scope and I am calling it from `onSubmit` function.

Comment: API call and response is working fine. Only after redirection to dashboard plain javascript is not working

Comment: What do you mean by "plain javascript" and "not working" ? calling UserLoginAPI does not works from dashboard ?

Comment: Plain Javascript means custom javascript which I written for onclick events, slider script etc. Not working mean those front end script are not working when redirect through `this.props.history.push('/dashboard')`

Comment: Ok probably this is a binding issue. Try to convert the function to arrow function to mantain context